# Moving maximum of a vector y where y changes with each step

Tags: algorithm, max

Setup: I have a vector **y** of length K.  Let y<sub>i</sub> be the i<sup>th</sup> element, and **y**<sub>-i</sub> be the (K-1)-vector of all elements except the i<sup>th</sup>, i.e., **y**<sub>-i</sub> = (y<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,...,y<sub>i-1</sub>,y<sub>i+1</sub>,...,y<sub>K</sub>).

Goal: Iteratively update each y<sub>i</sub> based on the max of **y**<sub>-i</sub>, i.e., y<sub>i</sub> ← foo(max(**y**<sub>-i</sub>)), where foo() is some known function.

So, my algorithm for doing this is basically:

for i = 1 to K:
    y<sub>i</sub> ← foo(max(**y**<sub>-i</sub>))

This works fine, but I'm searching for a more efficient algorithm that does not have to recompute the max of all K-1 elements of **y**<sub>-i</sub> for each iteration.  I imagine a better algorithm would use the fact that only one element of **y** changes each iteration.

P.S. I found other StackExchange questions about finding moving maximums, but none where **y** changes.

P.P.S. A little bit of context, in case anyone is wondering: I'm coding a Gibbs sampler, and the full conditional distribution of each y<sub>i</sub> depends on **y**<sub>-i</sub> only through its max (so foo is actually a random number generator where one of its parameters is set to max(**y**<sub>-i</sub>)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gets rid of the loop inside loop, so reduces the time from O(K^2) to O(K) at the expense of tripling the memory required:

```
Max_to_end[K+1] = -infinity
Max_from_beginning[1] = -infinity

for i = K down to 1
  Max_to_end[i] = max(Max_to_end[i+1],y[i])

for i = 1 to K
  y[i] = foo(max(Max_from_beginning[i],Max_to_end[i+1]))
  Max_from_beginning[i+1] = max(Max_from_beginning[i],y[i])
```

We have two new arrays, the maximum of all elements up to but not including y[i], and the maximum of all elements from y[i] inclusive onward.

There's danger of an off-by-one error, so please do check carefully, run comparisons with your existing routine, etc. It might make sense to change the algorithm to make both the Max_from_beginning and Max_to_end arrays include their end point. Not a big deal, whatever makes most sense in context.

Comment: The logic seems sound and some tests agree with my existing code.  One small fix: the first line should refer to Max_to_end, not Max_from_end.  Thanks very much, Edward!

Comment: A marginal improvement: Only the first element of Max_from_beginning needs to be initialized to -infinity, so the first for-loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Right ... I don't even know what I was thinking. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: One more thought: it's possible to reduce the additional memory required (if that's important) to n from 2n, by re-using the no-longer-needed elements of array Max_to_end to store elements of Max_from_beginning.